# 'setxkbmap -option caps:none' no longer works in 22.04.1

Tags: upgrade, capslock

After the upgrade to 22.04 earlier this week I can no longer turn off the CapsLock key with terminal command 'setxkbmap -option caps:none'.
Was this intentional?  Or, is there another way to do so?

Dick Silbar, silbar@swcp.com

---

Vanadium's suggestion to use Gnome Tweaks seems to do the job.  After installing it, go to *Keyboard and Mouse*, then to *Additional Layout Options*, then to *Capslock Behavior*, and turn on *Capslock Disbled*.  Pressing the CapsLock key now no longer turns on the little light above the numeric keypad.  I will see if that remains true in future log-ins.

Thank you, Vanadium

Comment: 22.04 defaults to Wayland. Switch back to Xorg.

Comment: You can use Gnome Tweaks to do that in the default Ubuntu desktop

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Vanadium's suggestion. I edited my query to say, in more detail, what I did to fix it.  (And, by the way, the fix persists even after a reboot.)